# Learning structures and arithmetic on their fields

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I'm learning structures right now and they make sense in my head but I'm having a hard time working with them. I'm reading a file using redirected standard input('<'). I loosely have been working on an example just to help me understand it better but am just not seeing any expected output. Its just a little example I came up with that should model the hour the bus arrived and the number of people on the bus. Disregarding time for clarity sake, I'm trying to add all the number of people who road the bus and print that. The sample input data is,

```
2 2
6 1
7 4
8 2
8 9
```

and I am running it via `a.out < input.txt`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc() and exit()

struct arrival_struct
{
    int time;       // time of arrival
    int count;      // number of passengers/seats arriving
};

int main(void) {

    struct arrival_struct arrivals;
    int *time[10]; // stores # of batches for passenger arriving at the same time
    int code;
    int totalPassenger=0;
    int i;
    int  *a; //dynamic memory base address
    int required[10]; // stores # of passenger arrive at the same time in batch
    int j=0;

    // read in code until eof
    while (scanf("%d", &code) !=EOF) {
        //load the first token into time[j]
        scanf("%d", *time[j]);
        *time[j] = arrivals.time;
        //load the second token into required[j]
        scanf("%d", required[j]);
        required[j] = arrivals.count;
        //increment totalPassenger by the count token that was read in
        totalPassenger = totalPassenger + required[j];

        a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*required[j]); //required[j] should be the number of passengers for that row
        scanf("%i %i", a->time, a->count);
        j++;
    }
    printf("total passengers: %d", totalPassenger);

}
```

I imagine there are plenty of syntax errors and such in here as I'm not very familiar with C and am just going through workshops. The main thing confusing me is reading it in from a file and ensuring you end up with the desired structure of

```
time: 2   count: 2   totalPassengers: 2
time: 6   count: 1   totalPassengers: 3
etc ..
```

Sorry if this is hard to understand I'm very new to the language and am trying to catch up to my peers. If my question isn't clear please just link me or explain a simple exactly of reading in from standard input and having a structure be filled.

EDIT:

```
struct arrival_struct {
    int time;
    int count;
};

int main(void) {
    int code;
    int totalPassenger=0;
    struct arrival_struct arrivals[10];
    int i=0;
    int j;
    while (scanf("%d", &code) !=EOF) {

        scanf("%d%d", arrivals[i].time, arrivals[i].count);
        totalPassenger += arrivals[i].count;
        i++;
    }
    printf("total passengers: %d", totalPassenger); //works
    for (j=0;j<5;j++)
        printf("time: %d\tcount: %d\n", arrivals[j].time, arrivals[j].count);

}
```

output : [image]

Comment: I don't get the question.

Comment: @Joshua My question is how to read from standard input into a structure that I can then do some operations on, like summing. I know it wasn't very clear sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding the value in `*time[j]` with a junk value from an undefined member of the structure. Assign the input you collected into the structure. `*time[j] = arrivals.time;` should be `arrivals.time = *time[j];`.

Also the variable `a` was declared `int *a` so it does not have the members count and time. The statement `scanf("%i %i", a->time, a->count);` will throw a syntax error.

An cleaner way to keep track would be to declare an array of `arrival_struct` and define the structs as you collect the input.

```
struct arrrival_struct arrivals[10];

while(...) {
scanf("%d%d", &arrivals[j].time, &arrivals[j].count);
totalPassenger += arrivals[j].count;
j++;
}
```

EDIT

```
while (scanf("%d%d", &arrivals[j].time, &arrivals[j].count) != EOF){
totalPassenger += arrivals[j++].count;
}
```

If one input fails the while loop body won't execute. You could check for errors outside the loop.

Comment: Once you're outside of this while loop how would you access and print the structure array? with a for loop and something like `printf("arrival time: %d\tarrival count: %d ", arrival[j].time, arrival[j].count);` ?

Comment: Exactly like that. As long as there is a valid `arrival_struct` object at the index it should work.

Comment: I seem to keep getting a segmentation fault error. Could you check my edit above and possibly point me in the right direction? I assume its because I'm going out of bounds somewhere with the struct array.

Comment: `scanf` takes pointers. Prefix the struct members with `&` to pass the address to `scanf`. `&arrivals[i].count` and the same to time.

Comment: Note that the number used for the while loop conditional is unused which will lead to weird side effects.

Comment: ah yes of course it requires the `&` silly me. Is there a more efficient way to use a conditional to loop until EoF rather than what I have? It is just what I've used in the past.  thanks again for all the help

Comment: You could do the input inside the conditional. See the edit.

Comment: even with the old conditional while loop, I'm getting the right totalpassengers however when I try to print out the structure I get a lot of weird output that doesnt match the input file. When printed, the first entry read `time: 2   count: 6` which isn't 2 2. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Is this with the new conditional?

Comment: I added a picture of the output(old conditional). When I use the new conditional I got a segmentation fault.

Comment: Where is the storage for each of the pointers in `int *time[10];` allocated?

Comment: With the old conditional the first 2 is read and assigned to `code` when evaluating the conditional. Inside the while loop body the next two numbers are read, 2 and 6. The same thing occurs every loop. This is the reason for the discrepancy in your output. The totalPassenger value is a lucky coincidence.

Comment: As for the new conditional I suspect it's your print loop causing the segfault. Try compiling with the print loop commented out.

Comment: ah I see this is why the conditional will have strange output. Is there not some syntax like `while(!EOF)`. I could try the new conditional again and mess with it a bit to see if I can get rid of the segmentation fault.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin unnecessary variable.

Comment: You could use while(1) in the conditional and then `continue` to leave the while loop. You don't need to if your while loop is `while (scanf("%d%d", &arrivals[j].time, &arrivals[j].count) != EOF){
      totalPassenger += arrivals[j++].count;
    }`

Comment: Yes this seems to have cleared everything up for the root of my confusion! There is a lot more to do that I didnt mention in the question for clarity sake and I think this will help me do those parts. :) Thanks again

Comment: No problem @Mikel

Comment: @can'tThinkOfAName agree with you completely.

Comment: Woops you use `break;` to leave a loop not `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking we do something like this. I don't like `scanf` for input but that's a different topic. Bad input is not handled because I won't fix `scanf` input handling.

```
/* dynamically allocated array of structs */
struct arrival_struct *arrivals = NULL;
size_t narrivals = 0; /* number of elements used */
size_t aarraivals = 0; /* number of elements allocated */

while (...)
{
    if (narrivals == aarrivals) {
        /* If we're out of space in the array, double the size. Initial size is 16 */
        arrivals = realloc(arrivals,
            sizeof(*arrivals) * (
                aarrivals = (aarrivals == 0) ? 16 : (aarrivals << 1)
            )
        );
    }
    /* read input */
    scanf("%d", &arrivals[narrivals].time);
    scanf("%d", &arrivals[narrivals].count);
    // ...
    ++narrivals; /* one more usable element in array */
}
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some comments to your code above explaining it a little? :)

Comment: @Mikel: That should help.

Answer (score 0):

While you already have a good answer, in your quest to understand the use of structures, you may be missing a large part of their benefit and use. You declare your struct, e.g.

```
struct arrival_struct {
    int time;       // time of arrival
    int count;      // number of passengers/seats arriving
};
```

You can then just declare an array of struct to store each component read from each line from the file and dispense with the plethora of additional variables. For instance, you can simply declare:

```
 #define MAXS 10     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
 ...
    struct arrival_struct arrivals[MAXS] = {{ .time = 0 }};
```

Which will declare an array of `10 struct arrival_struct` and initialize all values to zero.

Then, rather than risk falling into the many pitfalls of `scanf`, it is far better to read one line of data at a time with a *line-oriented input* function like `fgets` (or POSIX `getline`) and then parse the information from the buffer filled into the needed values. That way what remains in your input stream doesn't depend on the *conversion specifier* user or whether a *matching failure* occurs.

Simply declare a character buffer of sufficient size to hold each line (*Don't Skimp on Buffer Size!*) and read each line into a buffer. Then parse the needed values from the line with `sscanf`, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 1024
...
    size_t n = 0;
    char buf[MAXC];

    /* while array space remains, read each line from file into struct */
    while (n < MAXS && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d %d", &arrivals[n].time, &arrivals[n].count) == 2)
            n++;
```

While you could simply obtain your passenger count at the time you read from the file, presumably you will read the data at one point in your program and then later use the information as needed. So after reading all your file data into your array of struct, a simple function returning the passenger count can be as simple as:

```
size_t getpassengercount (struct arrival_struct *s, size_t n)
{
    size_t count = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count += s[i].count;

    return count;
}
```

Putting it altogether into a short-concise example reading your data file you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXS 10     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 1024

struct arrival_struct {
    int time;       // time of arrival
    int count;      // number of passengers/seats arriving
};

size_t getpassengercount (struct arrival_struct *s, size_t n)
{
    size_t count = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count += s[i].count;

    return count;
}

int main(void) {

    struct arrival_struct arrivals[MAXS] = {{ .time = 0 }};
    size_t n = 0;
    char buf[MAXC];

    /* while array space remains, read each line from file into struct */
    while (n < MAXS && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d %d", &arrivals[n].time, &arrivals[n].count) == 2)
            n++;

    printf ("total passengers: %zu\n", getpassengercount (arrivals, n));
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/passengercnt <dat/passengers.txt
total passengers: 18
```

Let me know if you have further questions.